# JQuery Images Width is Returning 0 Half of the Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question is similar to other questions posted but I have read through a bunch and I still haven't been able to figure this one out. I am trying to add a class based on the width of an image. Basically, if the image is 100vw I want to add a class called newTransform.

This code is working some of the time. However, other times the width is returning as 0. I have figured out that this is because I need to wait until the image has loaded before calling the width. I think I have done that here but it is not working.

```
$(function () {
    var galleryReel = $(".gallery-reel-item");

    galleryReel.each(function () {
      let img = $(this).load( "img");
      let width = img.width();
      let viewWidth = $(window).width();
      
        if (width == viewWidth) {
            $(this).addClass("newTransform");
        } 
      else {}
    });
});
```

UPDATED: My updated code is as follows. The only problem now is that it flashes the old style before applying the new.

```
$(function () {
  let timeToWait = 1000; // 1 second

  setTimeout(() => {
    var galleryReel = $(".gallery-reel-item");

    galleryReel.each(function () {
      let width = galleryReel.width();
      let viewWidth = $(window).width();
  
      if (width == viewWidth) {
        $(this).addClass("newTransform");
      } 
    });
  }, timeToWait);
});
```

SOLUTION: The solution I ended up going with is the following code while also adding some css to initially hide the gallery.

```
$(function () {
  let timeToWait = 1000; // 1 second

  setTimeout(() => {
    var galleryReel = $(".gallery-reel-item");

    galleryReel.each(function () {
      let width = galleryReel.width();
      let viewWidth = $(window).width();
  
      if (width == viewWidth) {
        $(this).addClass("newTransform");
      } 
    });
    
    //show the gallery
    $(".gallery-reel").css("visibility", "visible");
    
  }, timeToWait);
});
```

Comment: `let img = $(this).load( "img");` most certainly doesn't do anything that would wait for the image to load

Comment: Ok. How do I fix it?

Comment: Are `.gallery-reel-item` elements the `<img>` elements?

Comment: No. There are image elements inside of the .gallery-reel-item. However, I need the class added to the .gallery-reel-item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somewhere in your html code. This will initially be hidden...

```
<div class="gallery-items-container" style="visibility:hidden">
  //all your images are here
</div>
```

You can wrap your inner code with a setTimeout...

```
$(function () {

  let timeToWait = 1000; // 1 second

  setTimeout(() => {
    var galleryReel = $(".gallery-reel-item");

    galleryReel.each(function () {
      let img = $(this).load( "img");
      let width = img.width();
      let viewWidth = $(window).width();
  
      if (width == viewWidth) {
        $(this).addClass("newTransform");
      } 
    });

    //show the gallery
    $('.gallery-items-container').css('visibility', 'visible');

  }, timeToWait)
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work great. I did change the 1000 to 100 because it was flashing the old style before applying the newTransform style.

Comment: Ops! I realised that if I set the timetowait down to 100 then the code wasn't applying at all on some screens. Anyway we can fix this flash?

Comment: `let img = $(this).load( "img");` doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: I have changed it... please see my updated code above.

Comment: You can hide the gallery reel using css with visibility hidden. The once all the calculations have run you can show it.

Comment: I've added the extra code to hide and show the gallery. You can then increase the timeToWait back up to a sensible amount to let the images load.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I have used this code except I took out the let img = $(this).load( "img"); line.